# Return null if any of the integers are negative or more than 10

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to trying to return null if any of the integers are negative or more than 10. When I use this code, I get null, null, null. Instead of just null once. Expected: null, instead got: [null,null,null].

What could be the reason for this?

```
function upArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        var num = arr[i];
        if (num > 9 || num <= 0) {
            var x = null;
            return x;
        }  
    }
    {
            var toNum = parseInt(arr.join('')) + 1;
            arr = toNum.toString().split('').map(Number);
            return arr;
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/64xt6781/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so let me paraphrase to be sure if I understood the requirements correctly: You want this function to

1. return `null` if any of the elements in the array is below 0 or above 10
2. return `0` if that is not the case

Let me propose a direct implementation of the above: we'll check, using the `.some()` method if at least one of the collection's item does fulfill the first condition. If so, we will set the `hasOutOfBoundries` variable to true.

And if it's true, we'll return `null`, otherwise `0`:

```
function upArray(arr) {
    var hasOutOfBoundries = arr.some(function (item) {
        return item > 10 || item < 0;
    });
    return (hasOutOfBoundries) ? null : 0;
};
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some for details on using `.some()` method;